# How many academic STEM PIs are there in the United States?

Tags: united-states, reference-request

Are there statistics that are more specific than the NSF Science and Engineering Indicators that can tell me how many PIs doing STEM research there are in the United States?

Comment: u need to request data from funding agencies

Comment: STEM includes biology and medicine, right?

Comment: Science (broadly), yes, including the life sciences,physical sciences and biomedical.  thanks for asking GEdgar.